# **Forced stop when I am closing app while service running

Tags: android

My `Service` is running.
WAY 1:I did set stop `Service` when user pressed back button.
WAY 2:When user exit to home screen(with home key) and press home key then remove the app from list,device get this message:`Unfortunately, yourapp has stopped`
I know that user should stop service to close non-error app.
Is a way to stop service in WAY2?

MyService:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
    name = b.getStringArray("name");
    builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String i : name)
    {
        builder.append(i);
    }

    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Titraj/"+builder+".mp3"));
    player.start();    
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
}
```

**Edit:**

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Please, add exception trace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

The `with null` in the stacktrace says the `Intent` is `null`.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

> The Intent supplied to `startService(Intent)`, as given. This may be null if the service is being restarted after its process has gone away, and it had previously returned anything except `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`.